# How can i open fragment from RecyclerView adapter?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

In my application i want open `fragment` with `adapter`.
I write below codes for **button** in `RecyclerView` `adapter`.
**Fragment codes:**

```
public class SelectAddressFragment extends BaseFragment implements SelectAddressInterface {

    @BindView(R.id.selectAddressFrag_progressBar)
    ProgressBar selectAddressFrag_progressBar;
    @BindView(R.id.selectAddressFrag_list)
    RecyclerView selectAddressFrag_list;
    private PrefsUtils prefsUtils;
    private String phoneNumber;
    private APIs apIs;
    private List<Re> model = new ArrayList<>();
    private LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;
    private RelativeLayout changeAddressContent, newAddressContent;
    private SelectAddressAdapter adapter;
    private String sendAddressID, sendName, sendState, sendCity, sendAddress, sendPostalCode, sendPhone, sendCellPhone;

    public SelectAddressFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_address, container, false);

        ButterKnife.bind(this, v);
        apIs = ApiClient.getClient().create(APIs.class);
        linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        prefsUtils = new PrefsUtils(getActivity());
        if (prefsUtils.isExist(PrefsKeys.PHONE_NUMBER.name())) {
            phoneNumber = prefsUtils.getFromShared(PrefsKeys.PHONE_NUMBER.name());
        } else {
            phoneNumber = "";
        }
        changeAddressContent = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.changeAddressContent);
        newAddressContent = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.newAddressContent);
        adapter = new SelectAddressAdapter(getActivity(), model, this, getFragmentManager());

        getListAddressData();
        initRecyclerView(selectAddressFrag_list, adapter);

        return v;
    }
```

**I write above codes, but when click on button not open fragment!**

How can i fix it?

Comment: Add your whole recyclerview adapter and also add your code where you are setting it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can pass FragmentManager to your adapter constructor. Like,

```
 public FragmentManager f_manager;
    //in your constructor add FragmentManager
    public YourAdapterName(Context context, FragmentManager f_manager)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.f_manager = f_manager;
    }
```

in on click :

```
     holder.itemListDialog_edtBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                     // We can get the fragment manager
                   f_manager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.newAddressContent, new NewAddressFragment())
                        .commit();

            }
        })
    ;
```

Comment: can you edit your codes with my above codes? please

Comment: Show me this error : http://uupload.ir/files/9xf7_screen_shot_1396-10-07_at_11.57.38.png . how can i fix it?

Comment: Check my updated answer.

Comment: not work again and not open fragment:(

Comment: Keep your recyclerview adapter code and also your activity code

Comment: please see my update post and help me :(

Comment: what is the error than ?

Comment: not show me error! just not open fragment

Comment: Thanks my friend for you help <3

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to handle click events in fragments and use callback methods!
If you use the manager in fragments to get this:
GetChildFragmentManager ()

> adapter:

```
static class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    public interface OnItemCLickListener{
        void OnItemClick(int position);
    }

    private OnItemCLickListener mOnItemCLickListener;

    public void setOnItemCLickListener(OnItemCLickListener onItemCLickListener) {
        this.mOnItemCLickListener = onItemCLickListener;
    }

    @Override
    public ProgressViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        //...
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ProgressViewHolder holder, int position) {
        //...
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataList.size();
    }


    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            if(mOnItemCLickListener!=null){
                textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        mOnItemCLickListener.OnItemClick(getAdapterPosition());
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> Fragment:

```
mAdapter.setOnItemCLickListener(new RecyclerViewAdapter.OnItemCLickListener() {
            @Override
            public void OnItemClick(int position) {
                // TODO: 2017/12/28 ...
            }
        });
```